# Trying to generate hardwareID in C# and getting 'System.Management.ManagementPath' exception

Tags: c#

i want to ask about a way to avoid basic piracy of my software, learning the basics for now i want the software to run only on one machine.

As far as i understand i need to get some values (unique ones) so my software can run only on the machine that has that ID combination, in order to do that i can access to "Win32_Processor" (i will try to start for the processorId then add some others parts as motherboard or something else).

For that i run a task which looks for the processorId with WMI, but when i try to compile i get an exception.

This is the part of the code where i get it(being the error on the first sentence):

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
ManagementObjectSearcher cpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectCollection cpu_Collection = cpu.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpu_Collection)
{
...
}
```

> **" System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception.' " NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

And the value of cpu get the value null, so i think there's the problem

I have many System.Management.dll and i imported different ones to see if that's the problem with no results, googled for answers but couldn't find or understand them(as i'm starting on this topic).

To give more information other things i get are (it's in spanish):

La excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:

```
System.Management.MTAHelper.IsNoContextMTA()
System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(System.Type)
System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(string)
System.Management.ManagementPath.ManagementPath(string)
System.Management.ManagementPath.ManagementPath()
```

I suspect that **System.Management.dll** is the problem but i cannot get one that works

Also i try to open **wbemtest** and connect to **root\cimv2** without problems, when i get to the query `SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor` i get it with no problems.

Thanks, if i need to show more of my code just tell me

EDIT:

all i did to get the processorId is in a private static async task, which i called

```
 private static async Task<string> HardwareID()
```

when i want to make it public so i can get it from my main class program i do the following

```
public static string HardID => HardwareID().Result;
```

beign HardID the public string that i returned from my private task HardwareID() so i can pass it to my class program as:

```
  string hwid = classHardID.HardID;
```

when i commented this part on my class program i get no errors but i cannot visualize it

this is the error i get when i put that part again

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.

Comment: Change from : Win32_Processor to : Win32_Process

Comment: What is that Task supposed to return (and how)? Remove `Task.Run()` and try again. Are you trying to get the `UniqueId`? You won't get it. You can get the `ProcessorId`, for what is worth.

Comment: Im trying to get ProcessorId, i think i found out that the error isn't exactly where i mentioned, i will edit to add more info.
Changing the Win32_Processor to Win32_Process didn't worked 
Thanks for the asnwers

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62540865/150605) was asked yesterday but (incorrectly, in my opinion) closed as a duplicate of the canonical `NullReferenceException` question.  Did you ever find a solution to this?  If not, can you add specific version information for your OS and .NET Framework?  See [System.Management not initializing on some Server SKUs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24536) which originated from [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/24719#issuecomment-344964440).  One user got it to work by upgrading .NET Framework from 4.5 to 4.7.